# Sequence of zeroes

Tags: python, list

I have a list like

```
[[1,1,1],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,5,3],[2,4,4],[2,3,5],...]
```

I need to append a sequence of zeroes (max length is five) onto each `i` in my list and add `i[1]` into that sequence depending on the `i[2]` value.

E.g. for `i = 0`, the sequence of zeroes is `1,0,0,0,0`. The `i[1]` which is equal to `1` has been placed at the front because the `i[2]` value is `1`. Similarly, for `i = 3`, `i[1] = 1` so the sequence is `0,1,0,0,0` as the `i[2]` value is `2` => `1` goes in the 2nd place of the sequence of zeroes.

In general, the `i[1]` value will go in the `i[2]` place in the sequence of zeroes. If `i[[1] = 8` and `i[2] = 4` then sequence = `0,0,0,8,0`. Each of these sequences will need to appended onto the ith array.

My desired output is:

```
[[1,1,0,0,0,0],[2,1,0,0,0,0],[2,0,1,0,0,0],[2,0,0,5,0,0],[2,0,0,0,4,0],[2,0,0,0,0,5],...]
```

I'm not sure if this makes sense but please do ask for more clarification.

Comment: I'll go ahead and ask for clarification: you are stating what you are trying to achieve, but **what is the question you are asking?**

Comment: Yuck.  I don't know what you're trying to do here, but there's got to be a better data structure for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In your desired output, I think last one should be `[2,0,0,0,0,3]`. Just checking if I understood right.

Comment: @Lafexlos yep you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is one of the awful questions where you ask people to find a solution for dealing with some badly designed data structure. but today is Saturday and I have fun with oneliners:

```
d=[[1,1,1],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,5,3],[2,4,4],[2,3,5]]

left = [[x[0]]+[0]*(x[2]-1)+[x[1]] for x in d]
print [l + [0]*(5-len(l)) for l in left]
```

happy parsing

Comment: thanks for the answer. I agree with the data structure being a messing but I don't have much of a choice. Thanks again.